# Sharpness of (computable) convergence tests

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms

Every now and then I stumble across a rather elementary question:
$$\text{Let}  \; (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \; \text{be a sequence with} \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0. \; \text{Is there a test that reliable tests for convergence of} \; \sum_\mathbb{N} a_n ?$$

I suspect the answer is **no**, since otherwise, such a test would be taught besides the root / ratio test in Calculus 1 & 2. However, each iteration of those courses I've witnessed and the books I consulted all tacitly leave this issue out. They rather state that the taught tests are simply unconclusive if the result is 1.

In the light of the plethory of different, more fine-tuned tests that exist, I'm happy with the following variation:
$$ \text{Let} \; \alpha: n \mapsto a_n \; \text{be computable. Are there countably many computable tests} \; (T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \; \text{and a computable function} \; D \; \text{such that} \; T_{D(\{\alpha\})} \; \text{decides whether} \; \sum_\mathbb{N} a_n \; \text{converges?} $$

Here, I'm using $\{\alpha\}$ to denote a code for the function $\alpha$. I'm most interested in the case that the sequences are real, i.e., $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, although that slightly complicates the computability part. If it's easier to deal with rational or algebraic sequences, I'll take the restriction as well, and if it gets easier with c.e. functions instead of computable ones, that's fine too.

Comment: Leaving aside computability nuances, [Paul du Bois-Reymond](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Du_Bois-Reymond/) showed in the 1880s that there does not exist a convergence test that works for all series. See [Andrés E. Caicedo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/588527/13130) to *Is there a series where the terms tend to zero faster than the harmonic series but it still diverges?* and (for computability aspects) [Yuval Filmus's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/890602/13130) to *How to describe sequences that converge very slowly*.

Comment: For more about the issues mentioned in my previous comment, see [*The infinite and infinitesimal quantities of du Bois-Reymond and their reception*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.116.8707) by Gordon Fisher (1981) AND Section 4.7 (pp. 142-151) in Marion Scheepers's survey paper [*Gaps in* $\left(^{\omega}{\omega}, \prec \right)$](https://web.archive.org/web/20060906092209/http://math.boisestate.edu/~marion/research/order/gaps.pdf) AND [these historical notes](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/math-origins-orders-of-growth).

Comment: Thank you Dave for pointing out the Yuval's answer, it is precisely the answer I searched. I flaged the question as duplicate (I hope that's the correct way of handling this)